# Error in MainActivity when implement GDPR

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, admob

I need to add the GDPR box to the app.

I follow this instruction:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

My MainActivity.java file is written entirely like in this manual, but after that I can't run the application because I have the following errors:

```
MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                                   ^
      symbol:   variable activity_main
      location: class layout

MainActivity.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
                                                public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                                                                    ^
          symbol: class Nullable
        2 errors
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I tried changing extends AppCompatActivity to extends FlutterActivity but that doesn't change anything, the error is still exactly the same.

How can I deal with it?

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.my.app_name;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.ump.ConsentForm;
import com.google.android.ump.ConsentInformation;
import com.google.android.ump.ConsentRequestParameters;
import com.google.android.ump.FormError;
import com.google.android.ump.UserMessagingPlatform;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
    private ConsentForm consentForm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            loadForm();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.

                    }
                });
    }

    public void loadForm(){
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if(consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        /// Handle Error.
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```